# Image Caching With AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, afnetworking-2

The cache mechanism of AFNetworking is not working for me, I have an image of 500ko with big dimension and I want to cache it. But every time I close the application and open it again I have to wait for 20sec for the image to load so the cache system is not working here is the code:

I tried :

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

and then tried :

```
NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                      timeoutInterval:60];

[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                      success:nil
                      failure:nil];
```

Comment: Maybe 500kb is too much ? Any idea what is the maximum cacheable image size ?

Comment: Can I see how you configure the cache?

Comment: @Ricardo: Actually that's all what I have done, do I need to configure the cache in other place ?

Comment: @pe60t0: I want to handle all cases so I am testing with a big image. how can I find the maximum cacheable image size?

Comment: Yeah - just a thought - maybe there is a limit on it. Or maybe the cache mechanism itself is slow - but the image has been successfully cached ?

Comment: @pe60t0: in case it's cached the image should be displayed without any delay. So probably it's not cached, maybe I miss something in the configuration.

Comment: Try to have a look into the disk if the file has been saved somewhere.

Comment: @pe60t0 I have also changed the policy to : _"NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad: offline mode, load cache data regardless of expiration, do not go to source"_ and the image was not loaded so there is no image in the cache

Comment: @pe60t0 as you have mentioned, it was about the size

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSURLCache does not write to disk in its default so we need to declare a shared NSURLCache in app delegate :

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                          diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                          diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

[Reference](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/)

Comment: Should I pass the images into this `sharedCache` manually or AFNetworking will do it for us. In my case, the app is not using cached image when I reopen it.